# Asymptotic formula for “Self Numbers” $s_n$

Tags: asymptotics, decimal-expansion

While digging through some old notebooks today, I found a problem from a long time ago that I was never able to solve. It involves a sequence of positive integers called the “self numbers” defined such that $s_n$ is the nth positive integer for which the equation
$$k+\text{digit sum of }k = s_n$$
has no solution (this is is base 10, by the way). This sequence is [A003052 on OEIS](https://oeis.org/A003052).

It appears that this sequence grows asymptotically linearly, and I tried (but failed) to find the asymptotic rate at which it grows:

$$r=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s_n}{n}$$

Can anyone figure out how to calculate $r$, even in series or integral form?

**Note**: The best I was able to prove is that $r < 25/2$.

Answer (score 3):

U. Zannier in his paper `On the Distribution of Self-Numbers' proves a theorem about the number of self numbers less than $x$, specifically that $A(x)= Lx + O(\log^2(x))$ for some positive $L$. You can invert this function to get a statement about the $n$th self number growing linearly (in the same way that one can invert the prime number theorem $\pi(x) \sim x/\log(x)$ into $p_n\sim n\log(n)$, being careful with analytic asymptotic inverses). I'm not sure if an exact way to compute the constant is mentioned but that would be somewhere to look to get a sense of how to do what you want to do. His $L$ for decimal (or what is referred to in the paper as scale $g=10$) appears to be $\approx 0.0977$, which you invert to get the $r$ in your formula to be $\approx 10.24$. I don't know if there's a nice analytic form.

Comment: Could whoever downvoted my post let me know why they did, please? I'd appreciate constructive criticism if I've written something inaccurate rather than just a down a random downvote. Thanks!

Comment: I know that they are distributed linearly, and I have seen that paper. The purpose of this question is to look for a “nice analytic form.”

Comment: It was unclear whether you knew that it was linear because in your question you said "it appears that this sequence grows asymptotically linearly," so I thought a good first step was to actually confirm that before searching for a constant. Like I said before, and as reported in the book "Mathematical Constant" By Steven R. Finch on p. 179, no one seems to have yet established a form for $r$ unfortunately.  You could be the first.